# concatenateing string variables overwrites them

Tags: linux, string, bash, variables, echo

I have a problem to concatenate two string variables.
The second variable overwrites the first one.

Script:

```
subject1=$(grep -E -o "Exit.{0,12}" 123.log)
subject2=$(grep Transferred: 123.log)
completesubject="$subject1 / $subject2"
echo $completesubject
```

`subject1` contains `Exit status 0`, while `subject2` contains `Transferred: sent 308464915408, received 11704 bytes, in 14844.1`.

Now `completesubject` results in `/ Transferred: sent 308464915408, received 11704 bytes, in 14844.1 seconds`, but I want 
it to be `Exit status 0 / Transferred: sent 308464915408, received 11704 bytes, in 14844.1 seconds`.

What is the problem?

Comment: Are you sure subject1 is being set properly?  If you set `subject1` and `subject2` manually, does your concatenation work?  Try turning on `set -x` to see what your variables are actually getting set to

Comment: I guess '\r' is in subject2 :)

Comment: user3159253 is probably right, try `echo "$subject1 / $subject2"` and verify you have the same output. When you do, try `${subject2//\r/}` instead, this will strip any carriage returns.

Comment: Try `printf '[%q/%q]\n' "$subject1" "$subject2"` to see what the variables actually contain. As already surmised I expect you will see `\r` in the first value.

Comment: Hi everybody, thanks for your help! Yes it was CR LF! I used  `echo $subject1 | sed -e 's/\r//g'` to delete this.