# Perl print 2 variables overwrites the first

Tags: perl, printing

When I print 2 variables on a single line, the second variable overwrites the first one.  I suspect a "hidden" character in one of the strings, as described here [concatenateing string variables overwrites them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31070794/concatenateing-string-variables-overwrites-them)

How do I print "correctly"?  And how can I make Perl tell me exactly every single character in a string assigned to the variable?  If it's not a "hidden" character, then what's the problem?

Code is ...

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

print "\n\nstart\n\n";
open CFG, "sw.cfg"
        or die "Unable to open file sw.cfg: $!";
my $a;
my $b;
my $c;
while (<CFG>) {
    if (/interface/)  {
        $a = substr ($_, 10);
    }
    if (/description/) {
        $b = substr ($_, 12);
        chomp ($a);
        chomp ($b);
        # $c = join ("--", $a, $b);
        print "$a,\n";
        # print "$c\n"     
    }
}
```

Some of the input data from the file handle

```
interface FastEthernet0/1
 spanning-tree portfast
!
interface FastEthernet0/2
 spanning-tree portfast
!
interface FastEthernet0/3
 description AP STM
 spanning-tree portfast
!
interface FastEthernet0/4
 description PORTAGE
 spanning-tree portfast
    enter code here
```

What my script actually outputs...

```
    start

,astEthernet0/3
,astEthernet0/4
,astEthernet0/5
,astEthernet0/7
,astEthernet0/9
,astEthernet0/11
```

I'd think it should put the comma after it prints "FastEthernet 0/3"

This fixed the problem...

```
while (<CFG>) {
        **s/\r\n\z//;**
        if (/interface/)  {
```

Comment: Please provide some of the sample input data, as well as what output you'd like to see. Without seeing data, we don't know if `interface` and `description` are on the same line. That's one likely issue, as is the fact that you may be printing from the wrong location.

Comment: interface FastEthernet0/1
 spanning-tree portfast
!
interface FastEthernet0/2
 spanning-tree portfast
!
interface FastEthernet0/3
 description AP STM
 spanning-tree portfast
!
interface FastEthernet0/4
 description PORTAGE
 spanning-tree portfast

Comment: also, in the current code you don't print 2 variables, you only print "$a,\n";

Comment: is that one line of the file, or many. Update your question, paste in 5 or so lines, and ensure they are separated properly so we know what we're dealing with. I'm suspecting `$a, $b, $c` are being overwritten on every iteration/line

Comment: I was trying to print $a, some spaces, then $b originally.  When that didn't work, I then decided to just print $a with a comma AFTER the value.  I tried to join the two variables into a new string, same problem.

Answer (score 3):

You are reading a Windows-style text file (CRLF endings) when a unix-style text file (LF endings) is expected.

Either,

- convert the file (e.g. using `dos2unix`),
- add a `:crlf` layer when you open the file, or
- remove the CR yourself (e.g. by using `s/\s+\z//;` instead of `chomp;`).

Comment: That was it!  I added s/\r\n\z//; to the loop, now it works right.  So what did that do, and why is this even a problem?  I'm not running Windows, I have a Mac.

Comment: There are (at least) 2 standard line end character sequences; Unix-style ("\n"), and Windows-style ("\r\n").  Your file was obviously created with the latter, which would be unusual on a Mac, but not impossible. Depends on what you used to create it.

Comment: That's what I don't understand.  The "sw.cfg" file was created by running expect module from a perl script, SSH to a switch, typing "show run", and capturing the output to a file specified in $exp->logfile ("sw.cfg","w"); line.  The script was run on my Mac.